# How to add async await for multiple nested calls

Tags: nuxt.js

I'm using fetch hooks. For fetch hooks to work properly, I need to add `async` and `await` for the nested multiple calls .

In the component I used fetch hook

```
async fetch () {
    await this.$store.dispatch('pages/getPagesById', this.$route.params.id)
    await this.$store.dispatch('pages/getPage', this.$route.params.id)
  }
```

```js
async getPagesById({ commit, state }, pageId) {
    commit('setLoading', true)
    await pages.findBy(pageId).then((response) => {
      const pagesId = response.data.page_item
      const queuesId = []
      const defaultTitles = []
      const breakingTitles = []
      const queryParams = {
        _sort: 'created_at:DESC',
        _limit: 10
      }
      pagesId.forEach((item, index) => {
        item.queue && item.queue.type === 'breaking' ? breakingTitles.push(item.title) : defaultTitles.push(item.title)
        if (item.queue) {
          queuesId.push(pages.findQueueById(item.queue.id))
        } else if (item.tags) {
          const tagsParams = Object.assign({}, queryParams, { tags: item.tags.id })
          queuesId.push(articles.findByTags(tagsParams))
        }
      })
      Promise.all(queuesId).then((response) => {
        const articleItemQueue = response.map((item, index) => {
          return item.data
        })
        commit('setdefaultTitles', defaultTitles)
        commit('setBreakingTitles', breakingTitles)
        commit('setPagesArticles', articleItemQueue)
        commit('setLoading', false)
      })
      commit('setLoading', false)
    })
  }
```

Any help would be great.

Comment: What did you try ? Where does it fail ?

Comment: @BTL Edited the above code, so that you could get properly
I wanted to use async and await for fetch hooks to work properly

it works on navigated the routes, but when I refresh the page, then fetch hooks doesn't work

Comment: Seems that you mixed up promise syntax and async/await syntax. You have no need for then() in async/await, you can store the result of the call like this: `const result = await pages.findBy(pageId)`

Comment: Thanks, the way you tell, it solved my problem 
Much thanks to you